# Entity Framework upward relation

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-6

Let´s say we have two EF6 classes.

```
public class Store
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Seller> Sellers { get; set; }
}

public class Seller
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Stores> Stores{ get; set; }
}
```

And the two EF6 configuration classes.

```
public class StoreConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Store>
{

    public StoreConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Stores");
        HasKey(q => q.Id);

        HasMany(s => s.Sellers)
            .WithMany(s => s.Stores)
            .Map(me =>
            {
                me.MapLeftKey("Id");
                me.MapRightKey("Id");
                me.ToTable("StoreSellers");
            });

    }
}


public class SellerConfig: EntityTypeConfiguration<Seller>
{

    public SellerConfig()
    {
        ToTable("Sellers");
        HasKey(q => q.Id);
    }
}
```

This approach works fine if I want to get the sellers querying the Stores and include the Sellers via Include(). But how can I access the store name of each seller from Sellers like:

```
var sellers = MyContext.Sellers; //Considering Sellers a DbSet<Seller>
foreach (var seller in sellers){
    var storename = seller.Store.Name;
}
```

Comment: you have a many to many relationship between te tables. which means you can have multiple stores in seller. try foreach (var seller in seller) {foreach (var store in seller.stores ) (dostuff())}

Comment: I can change the relationship, in fact, I want one-to-many relationship... the seller can be only in one store.

Comment: Then, you have to change `ICollection<Store> Stores` to `public Store Store {get; set;}` and also change your configuration. After that you can make `seller.Store.Name` inside your foreach loop.